# Selenium WebDriver (Java). Click by middle button. Double click by middle and right button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, webdriver, mouseevent

Let's say, I have an email field like this in WebDriver environment:

`@FindBy(id = "email")
    WebElement fldEmail;`

and (I know, it sounds oddly, but) I was trying to find handlers for middle and right mouse buttons, therefore I found only for right-clicking, like this:

```
new Actions(driver).contextClick(fldEmail).perform();
```

is there some way to simulate **middle** clicking and **double clicking** by **middle/right** buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Actions class in selenium has these features:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
@FindBy(id = "email")
WebElement fldEmail

//Double click
action.moveToElement(fldEmail).doubleClick().perform();

//Mouse over
action.moveToElement(fldEmail).perform();

//Right Click
action.contextClick(fldEmail).perform();
```

For **Middle Clicking** you can use **Robot Java API** and integrate it with your selenium framework.